# Saving to coredata from different APIs when you have relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, swift5

I have two different APIs to get Accounts and Contacts, where in the Core-Data model I have made an inverse relationship with the assumption of one Account could have many Contacts. My question is when I'm in the contacts screen (when I call the GET Contacts API using the Account Id), whats the best way to save those contacts in to that specific account. Entity relationship as follow.

[image]

my partially completed code as bellow, but i guess its wrong as im getting zero contacts when I fetch them back.

```
 func saveContactfor(accountID:String,data:[Array],isAddedFromDevice:Bool) {
    let request:NSFetchRequest<Account> = Account.fetchRequest()

           do {
               let searchResults = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
                   for account in searchResults {

                      if account.account_Id == accountID {
                       print("ID found in already saved Accounts")
                        for contact in data {

                            account.contacts?.adding(contact.dictionary) //contact.dictionary-> i have written a utils method to convert an object array to [[String:String]] which is an array of dictionaries
                        }
                        try managedObjectContext.save()
                      }


                    }


           print("Contacts Updated")
           } catch {
            print("Error in saving contacts from api to coredata")
           }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using relations you should be pretty near to what you need to do. All items need to be updated; account and contacts so you need to add relation one way or another.

The other one would be to use `contact.account = account` which looks more reasonable.

In the code you provided I am confused about a few things:

1. How you append your contacts. Should this not be `account.contacts = account.contacts?.adding(contact.dictionary)`?
2. Why do you fetch all contacts? Use predicates to extract only those with given ID.
3. Should possibly old accounts be deleted?

I would expect your (pseudo) code to look something like this:

```
func saveContacts(_ contacts: [ContactDetailModel], forAccount accountID: String) throws {
    // Fetch or create an account
    let account: Account = try Account.findWithID(accountID) ?? Account.createNewInstance(accountID: accountID)
    // Assign account
    contacts.forEach { $0.account = account }
    // Save database
    try saveContext()
}
```

I think you should be able to imagine what the 3 methods do for you. Remember you can mark your method to throw by using `throws` which can be huge convenience in such cases.

Now to also clear old accounts a bit more work may be needed:

```
func saveContacts(_ contacts: [InputContactData], forAccount accountID: String) throws {
    // Fetch or create an account
    let account: Account = try Account.findWithID(accountID) ?? try Account.createNewInstance(accountID: accountID)

    // Match accounts
    // Get all current contacts
    var depletingContacts: [ContactDetailModel] = (account.contacts.allObjects as? [ContactDetailModel]) ?? [ContactDetailModel]()
    contacts.forEach { newContact in
        if let index = depletingContacts.firstIndex { $0.contactID == newContact.id } {
            // The contact with this ID already exists. Remove it from array and assign new values
            let contact: ContactDetailModel = try depletingContacts.remove(at: index)
            contact.fillWithInputData(newContact)
        } else {
            // This contact is not yet in database. A new item needs to be created
            let contact: ContactDetailModel = try ContactDetailModel.newInstance()
            contact.fillWithInputData(newContact)
            contact.account = account
        }
    }
    // Clean up all old contacts.
    // The contact that are still left in depletingContacts were not part of input contacts and need to be deleted
    depletingContacts.forEach { try $0.removeFromDatabase() }


    // Save database
    try saveContext()
}
```

This is now a step further. I added `InputContactData` which is the data you receive from whatever service you are using and is not yet in core data.

Then an account is found or created. When iterating through each of new contacts the code tries to first match an existing one with a new item. Either an existing item is updated or a new one is created. Since an existing item is removed (depleted) from array of existing contacts the depleting array is left with contacts that have been deleted. So all of those may be removed from database.

This is a procedure where relation is one-to-many. Many-to-many would have a similar approach but a bit different.

I hope the rest of the code speaks for itself.

Comment: answer to your questiosn as follow:- [ContactDetailModel] is an array of objects which gets from the API which i wants to save in to my accounts object. technically thats my objective

Comment: would u kindly replace with actual syntaxes, foreach doesnt work on swift